# Deploying nodejs app with Open Shift PaaS

Tags: node.js, express, openshift, paas

I'm starting with Open Shift PaaS and I picked a node.js app as my first try.

So far I'm getting a [503](http://nodejs-veryfirsttest.rhcloud.com/) when I try to access my app site.

I've tried:

- Set my github repo,
- set the ssh key at github and made Open Shift have it,
- created a very simple app using express (I did install express by npm)
- did commit and pushed all changes,
- I did install rhc and ran `rhc app restart -a nodejs`

But I can't get it to work.

The `rhc tail -a nodejs` outputs:

> ```
> DEBUG: Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/531be41fe0b8cd3d12000003/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js'
>     at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
>     at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
>     at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
>     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
>
> DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 1
>
> DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
> ```

This is my `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express')
var server = new express()
server.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"))


server.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.send(200)
})

server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 80)
```

> ## EDIT

I've renamed app.js to server.js, did git add, commit and push, restarted app with rhc. but it's not working yet though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can name your main script whatever you want, [as long as the contents of your `package.json` file accurately describes your recommended server init process](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#main)

I've written up a blog post that outlines [the two main steps for getting your Node.js project to run on OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps):

1. [Update your `package.json` file, documenting your server init process (main, scripts.start)](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#package_json).
2. [Adapt your code to rely on environment variables for runtime configuration details](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#env_vars): server ip, port, domain name, db passwords, and other custom tokens

Make sure to [document your preferred deployment process in your project's README file as well](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#documentation)

Comment: I will start over. To be honest I first did a very naive configuration of my app. I didn't even have a `package.json` file.

Comment: I have a question, what when I already created the app on openshift web interface? Will rewriting `package.json`, npm installing and starting and so doing proper git commands for later rhc restarting will get it to work?

Comment: I would consider starting from a known-good state.  The vanilla nodejs cart will automatically provide a basic "hello world" example app. This is what you get when you don't supply any initial source.

Comment: You could also start from a [quickstart](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types?search=Nodejs) or example app and edit from there.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, after fixing both those issues, adding and committing your changes, and pushing the changeset to OpenShift; you should be able to get your current hosted app to work.

After verifying the changes, you could also push them back up to your repo on GitHub, making that repository OpenShift-compatible, and instantly launchable from OpenShift's web interface (no 503s or changes required next time around).