# Deploying express js app in openshift

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openshift

I am trying to deploy expressjs app in openshift. In my app folder, I have copied my express js application folder. As per [Deploying nodejs app with Open Shift PaaS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279605), in app.js file of express application, I have added

```
app.set('port', 8080); 
app.set('ipaddr', "a.b.c.d");
```

Also, in package.json, I have set value of 'main' key as app.js. I have also changed given express version to 4.8 . After pushing all the changes and node modules, when I hit my url, it says

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing? AS per the error log below, sever is not reading at the given port i think:

```
Error: listen EACCES
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
at listen (net.js:1061:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/540091a45973ca08d9000732/app-root/runtime/repo/project1/app.js:18:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node project1/app.js exited with code 8
```

I have even changed the `app.js` to this

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080); 
app.set('ipaddr', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Can you post any errors that you get in your logs? You can view them with rhc tail command, or ssh into your application and look in the ~/app-root/logs dir.

Answer (score 0):

Okkk...here is what i was doing wrong....

I needed to replace existing server listen code to this:

```
 server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
  });
```

In my app.js